# Read route params from directly entered url in app

Tags: javascript, angular, angular4-router

My question would be regarding angular 4, how to get route params, if for example a user gets on your page with, instead of the default url, like for example `http://localhost:3000/`, to something like `http://localhost:3000/user/:id`, and to be able to pick up the `:id` from that url (user has directly entered it in the browser, not navigating through the app).

In the example bellow same component is used, mainly because of needing to catch that id and dispatch other actions, if its present, and that would be it.

I have tried playing around with `ActivatedRoute` but from what I could tell so far, that only works when navigation throughout the app, from within the app, not in this case, which always returns a null value if that url is directly entered in the browser, it gets redirected to the default `/` route and that would be it.

Any tips or pointers are much appreciated

app.routing-module.ts

```js
import {hookComponent} from './hook.component';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HookComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'user/:id',
    component: HookComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

hook.component

```js
import {Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'hook',
  templateUrl: 'hook.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['hook.component.scss']
})
export class HookComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       console.log('params are', params); //null?
    });

  }
}
```

Comment: what happens when you import RouteModule.forRoot() directly to your app.module ?

Comment: well, nothing much, just using the routes directly from there, didn't notice any hickups or some sorts, the app itself its much larger than the example presented, and works pretty well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way is already ok, but in your example `params` is an array and you can access to `:id` by calling `params['id']`:

```
this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
  console.log('params are', params['id']);
});
```

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vmewyy) is an working example on stackblitz.

Comment: yep, seems to be working now, need to dig around some more, thanks for the help, and the demo, really appreciate it, makes things way easier this way :)

Answer (score 1):

Access current `url` via `Location`

```
public  constructor(location:Location) {
  let url = location.prepareExternalUrl(location.path());
}
```

and parse out `id` from this.

Comment: thanks for the tip, but still no luck with this one, returns just base url `/`, not the matched path

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is log the `params.id`; try using the `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` like this.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.route.snapshot.params.id);
}
```

If you want to check if the `params.id` is present, maybe do something like:

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'hook',
  templateUrl: 'hook.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['hook.component.scss']
})
export class HookComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {

  hasId: boolean = false;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if(this.route.snapshot.params.id !== null)
    {
        // do magic....
    }
  }
}
```